# Update after MailEnable manual MAI copy

Tags: email, email-server

I've manually restored mai files after I had to recreate mail account. Now Outlook like clients are able to download those mails but in webmail (MailEnable Webmail 9.00) I cannot see any of those manually copied mails.

Is there a command line or any tool to refresh mailbox indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting **_index.xml** files inside Inbox (or any other account related) folder will force MailEnable to rebuild index(es). This will solve the problem.